# How to actually use node inspector?

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a script that is defined as

```
"watch": "nodemon --inspect=0.0.0.0:3000 --legacy-watch server.js"
```

When I run this docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  server:
    image: node:14.18.2
    volumes:
      - "./app:/app"
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    env_file:
      - "config/config.env"
      - "config/secrets.env"
    working_dir: "/app"
    command: ["npm", "run", "watch"]
```

I get an error of `Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 0.0.0.0:3000`

I really don't understand because i followed the docs. what am i missing?

Comment: This setup doesn't seem like it's really making much use of Docker.  Can you directly run `npm run watch` on your host without this Compose setup?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the address is already in use. This means that another process - most probably an instance of your server - is already listening on `0.0.0.0:3000`.

Check your running docker instances with `$ docker ps -a` and stop the one that is running on this address with `$ docker stop container_name`.

See:

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/
- https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stop/

If there is no docker container running on this address, something else on your computer is using that address. The safe way would be to use a different port for your server then.

Comment: I'm trying to attach a debugger, but when debugger is running i can't add breakpoints

Comment: Which docs have you been following? And have you tried my solution?